# Illegal start of expression in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I'm getting an "illegal start of expression error". I've been searching for answers and cant find out, if I'm using the brackets incorrectly or not but I've tried it without the brackets and with them and cant seem to get past this 1 error. I could use some assistance. 
 Thank you :)

```
public class LIANGLAB1
{
    public static void main(String[] argv){

    gasStation A = new gasStation(3.39, 3.49);
    gasStation B = new gasStation(3.19, 3.39);

    A.sellregular(10);    A.sellregular(10);
    B.sellregular(11);    B.sellregular(12);

    if (A.moreprofit(B)) System.out.println("station A is more profitable");
   else System.out.println("station B is more profitable");

    gasStation G[] = new gasStation[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) G[i] = new gasStation(3.19,3.39);
        {gasStation highest =G[0];}

    for (int i=1;i<10;i++) 
        {if (G[i].moreprofit(highest)) highest = G[i];
            {System.out.println("highest total sales is" +highest.sales+ );}
                                                          //ERROR IS HERE
        }
    }
}
```

```
class gasStation
{
    double regularprice;
    double superprice;
    double sales;

        public gasStation(double r, double s)
    {regularprice = r; superprice = s; sales = 0;}

    public void sellregular(double gallons)
    {sales += regularprice * gallons;}

    public void sellsuper(double gallons)
    {sales += superprice * gallons;}

    public void gouge()
        {superprice *= 2; regularprice *=2;}

    public boolean  moreprofit(gasStation other)
        {return sales > other.sales;}
}
```

Comment: `highest.sales+ );}`... remove the last plus. And please: use proper indentation and linebreaks. It helps readability. Having a consist (and generally accepted) coding style helps readability, not only for yourself but also (especially!) for others looking at your code.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code that it's hard to know where to begin.  Wrong from top to bottom.

Comment: That's the weirdest brace style I've seen yet.

Comment: Please try to be less idiosyncratic with your coding style.

Comment: sorry, im an amatuer.

Comment: That is no excuse for a horrible coding style, I have never seen a tutorial or book that would suggest such a horrible coding style. And if you would have looked at any other Java code you would have been able to discern a lot of commonalities in coding style between different authors. Your code looks like you are bashing keys in the hope it eventually works. A starting point (but not the holy grail) is the old [Sun Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer with the corrections, but really, you could easily see those just from properly formatting your code. Those curly braces were all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) G[i] = new gasStation(3.19,3.39);
    {gasStation highest =G[0];}
```

to this

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    G[i] = new gasStation(3.19,3.39);
    gasStation highest =G[0];
}
```

And to improve code readability, you should really consider sticking to one statement per line.

EDIT:

```
for (int i=1;i<10;i++) 
    {if (G[i].moreprofit(highest)) highest = G[i];
        {System.out.println("highest total sales is" +highest.sales+ );}//ERROR IS HERE
    }
}
```

change it to:

```
for (int i=1;i<10;i++){ 
    if (G[i].moreprofit(highest))
        highest = G[i];
}
System.out.println("highest total sales is" +highest.sales);
```

There is no reason to open curly braces for single println statements.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the Java coding standards.  You aren't following them.  It makes your code hard to read.

Good names matter.  Put more thought into naming classes, methods, and variables.  Your aim should be easy understanding and readability.

This code compiles and runs fine.

```
public class LIANGLAB1 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        GasStation gasStationA = new GasStation(3.39, 3.49);
        GasStation gastStationB = new GasStation(3.19, 3.39);

        gasStationA.sellRegular(10);
        gasStationA.sellRegular(10);
        gastStationB.sellRegular(11);
        gastStationB.sellRegular(12);

        if (gasStationA.hasMoreProfit(gastStationB)) System.out.println("station A is more profitable");
        else System.out.println("station B is more profitable");

        GasStation arrayOfGasStations[] = new GasStation[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            arrayOfGasStations[i] = new GasStation(3.19, 3.39);
        }

        GasStation highest = arrayOfGasStations[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            if (arrayOfGasStations[i].hasMoreProfit(highest)) {
                highest = arrayOfGasStations[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("highest total sales is" + highest.sales);
    }
}

class GasStation {
    double regularprice;
    double superprice;
    double sales;

    public GasStation(double r, double s) {
        regularprice = r;
        superprice = s;
        sales = 0;
    }

    public void sellRegular(double gallons) {
        sales += regularprice * gallons;
    }

    public void sellSuper(double gallons) {
        sales += superprice * gallons;
    }

    public void gouge() {
        superprice *= 2;
        regularprice *= 2;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreProfit(GasStation other) {
        return sales > other.sales;
    }
}
```